# Set Proxy-Connection HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#

Estou tentando realizar o envio WCF via SOAP.
Consegue enviar via SOAPUI, conforme imagem existe o parâmetro "Proxy-Connection":

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No C# não existe esse parâmetro "Proxy-Connection":

```
        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://flnws001qae.nexxera.com:80/nexxeraws/v2/SkylineWSv2");
        req.Method = "POST";
        req.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate");
        req.ContentType = "multipart/related; type=\"text/xml\"; start=\"<rootpart@soapui.org>\"; boundary=\"---- = _Part_62_642526802.1564766469118\"";
        req.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "");
        req.Headers.Add("MIME-Version", "1.0");
        req.Host = "flnws001qae.nexxera.com:80";
        req.UserAgent = "Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)";
        req.KeepAlive = false;

        re.proxy-connection = "keep-alive" //não existe método
        req.Headers.Add("Proxy-Connection", "Keep-Alive"); //erro {"O cabeçalho 'Proxy-Connection' deve ser modificado com a propriedade ou o método adequado.\r\nNome do parâmetro: name"}
```

Alguém sabe como passo o valor para Proxy-Connection?

Comment: mas no soapui, você está usando credenciais (usuario/senha)?

Comment: Ricardo sim eu passo dentro do header.

Comment: então o que precisa fazer é setar as suas credencias no objeto `req.Credentials`, por exemplo assim: `req.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("usuario", "senha");`

Comment: Ricardo estou já estou passando as Credenciais. Mas tenho o retorno Erro 500, a única coisa que vi diferente do soapui e da minha aplicação é esse parâmetro "Proxy-Connection", quero passar esse campo por parâmetro. Conforme descrito não estou conseguindo passar.

Comment: sempre que usei autenticação esse header é controlado pelo wcf, acho que não consegue setar ele explicitamente, mas tenho certeza que é adicionado, mas geralmente não crio a chamada usando `HttpWebRequest`, constumo deixar o .net criar as classes proxy quando importo o contrato, dai uso o `ClientCredentials` e funciona bem